# how to display only time in jquery datepicker?

Tags: jquery

I want to display only time from jquery datepicker.
my current code is

```
$('#field-start_t_a').datetimepicker({
  showDate:false, 
   showSecond: true,

   timeFormat: 'hh:mm'
});
```

current output is

```
05/31/2013 00:12
```

required output is

```
00:12
```

Comment: Not really an answer, but there is [a jQuery timepicker plugin](http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/) which might be of use to you.

Comment: i think you are looking for timepicker more than datepicker

Comment: updated the live example in my answer to include the calendar icon, looks a little cleaner :-)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just set dateFormat to an empty string `dateFormat: ''`

```
$('#field-start_t_a').datetimepicker({
    dateFormat: '',
    timeFormat: 'hh:mm tt'
});
```

(this is a little strange that you only want to set time from the datetimepicker, because you can also do `$('#field-start_t_a').timepicker();` and only the time options show)

Comment: the fiddle doesn't seem to work for me, is it still correct? thanks

Comment: the fiddle was using an external js resource located here: http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/js/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js , if you go to that link you'll see it's been removed.

Comment: Even after including the timepicker addon js file, it shows picker for both date and time.

Comment: @AnantGupta you'll need to give me a link to a fiddle or something so I can see what's wrong.

Comment: Its the same fiddle link you posted. I just added a the addon link to it. Anyways, I found another jquery UI pick by now. Thanks.

Comment: oh I see...looks like I'll have to update the fiddle, for anyone landing on this in the future...

Comment: There are a few js errors on the console when I try to run the fiddle currently.

Comment: Using `.timepicker()` rather than `.datetimepicker()` appears to be what the OP is after.

Comment: Fiddle doesn't work, but using `timepicker` with the `timeFormat` works. (FYI)

Answer (score 10):

try a code like this:

```
<script>
  $('#time_input').datetimepicker({
     datepicker:false,
      format:'H:i'
  }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 8):

```
$('.picker').datetimepicker({
    dateFormat: '',
        timeFormat: 'hh:mm tt',
        **timeOnly: true**
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Just adding a simple solution. By adding only this , you can get a time only date picker

```
$('YOUR_SELECTOR').datetimepicker({
        format: "HH:mm"
});
```

Simple solution, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">                                   

$("#time_field_id").datetimepicker({                   
dateFormat: '', 
timeFormat: 'hh:mm tt', 
timeOnly: true                                   
 }); 

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

None of these solutions worked for me.  After some playing around I saw the following worked. What I was looking for was to put a time (in hours:minutes) in a form.

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#from").datetimepicker({
            dateFormat: '',
            datepicker:false,
            pickDate: false,
            format: "H:i",
            timeOnly:true

        });
        $("#end").datetimepicker({
            dateFormat: '',
            datepicker:false,
            pickDate: false,
            format: "H:i",
            timeOnly:true
        });

    });


</script>
```

When I now view my form I get the following:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
   $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
        format:'H:i:s',
        inline: true,
        sideBySide: true
   })
});
```

try this .worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Try this, works like a charm !

```
$('.time_only').datetimepicker({
    pickDate : false ,
    format: 'hh:mm' 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

{
timeFormat: 'hh:mm tt',
timeOnly: true
}