# Datetimepicker doesn't work right. Error: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datetimepicker

In my form I have a textboxfor. In this textboxfor I want a datetimepicker that will only show the hours and minutes, like this: 12:16. When I start the project the content of the textbox is: 12:00. That is good. But if I click on the textbox then I get the error: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined.

In my Model:

```
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:hh:mm}", ApplyFormatInEditMode=true)]
    public DateTime FromTime { get; set; }
```

The HTML:

```
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Alert.FromTime, "{0:hh:mm}", new { id="timepicker", @class="input-append"})
```

Javascript:

```
    $('#timepicker').datetimepicker({
        pickDate: false,
        pickSeconds: false
    });
```

Another problem is if I don't give any attention to the error and change the time in the datetimepicker then the content of the textbox is changed to the date of today: 12/04/2013. And I want only the hours and minutes.

How can I solve this?

Here i have some printscreens:

This is when I open my application:

[image]

Here I click on the textbox and get a datetimepicker:

[image]

And this happens when I change the time:

[image]

Comment: Try using `timepicker()`. That solves the time issue (hopefully).

Comment: I tried, but then i get the error: Object [object Object] has no method 'timepicker'

Comment: It's another plugin. [link](http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/)

Comment: [Another Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16862897/how-shows-only-time-in-jquery-datepicker)