# jquery datetime picker function

Tags: jquery

I have created a function for the jquery date/time picker

```
function date_picker(t, format) {
    format = format || "Y-m-d";

    $(t).datetimepicker({
        mask:true,
        lang:'en',
        format:format,
        datepicker:true, 
        timepicker:true, 
    });
}
```

I call it on input fields:

```
<input onclick="date_picker(this, 'Y-m-d');" />
```

I am having 2 issues, firstly how can I only include `datepicker` if the format includes the date and vice versa - how can I only include `timepicker` if the format includes time?

The second thing, is if the input is clicked into it shows the mask and then as soon as the input is clicked out of the current date/time will show.

How can it be so if not date/time is selected from the picker, the input stays blank.

Comment: how you are identifying that whether date should be picked or time?

Comment: just using the format (for example, it could be set as 'Y-m-d' or 'Y-m-d H:i:s')

Comment: are you using different inputs to decide on what to pick? if yes, you can write custom login inside your created function depending on the value of format. Sorry, if i didn't get your question.

Comment: just standard inputs as i put above and its determined using the format

Comment: i think your question has already been answered, refer [how-to-display-only-time-in-jquery-datepicker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16862897/how-to-display-only-time-in-jquery-datepicker)

Comment: i dont think so - read it again, they are different questions

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104728/discussion-between-ravi-and-charlie).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

personally, I would do something like:

```
<input type="date" value="2016-02-27"><input type="time" value="16:07">
```

Then you get what you want for free. However, what you are asking for:

psudo code:

```
<input name="datepicking" onclick="date_picker(this, 'Y-m-d');" />

var booltime = false;
var booldate = false;
if (format == "Y-m-d") booldate = true;
if (format == "Y-m-d H:s") booltime = true;
```

then

```
$(t).datetimepicker({
    mask:true,
    lang:'en',
    format:format,
    datepicker:booldate, 
    timepicker:booltime, 
});
```

then you still need to change the value of the input field

Comment: yep, that would work but what if the format is different - it could be either 'Y-m-d' OR 'd-m-Y'

Comment: <input type="date" value="2016-02-27">