# Remove date on top of datetimepicker only time

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have form, I want to show time when I pick it, but It show date and time
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljSyT.png)

I want to remove it, cause no sense
My coffee:

```
$('#time1').datetimepicker
format: 'hh:ii'
autoclose: true
startView: 1
```

My slim:

```
#time1.input-group.date
  input.form-control type="text" 
    span.input-group-addon
      span.glyphicon.glyphicon-time
```

Pls help me T_T

Comment: Please check out [these answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16862897/how-to-display-only-time-in-jquery-datepicker).

Comment: I tried all it but is not working

Answer (score 0):

```
 # In your cofee it can be like this    
 $('#time1').datetimepicker
   pickDate: false
   format: 'LT'
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.